# VBA 'Not an Object Error'

Tags: vba, excel

In just about every other language, there'd be no reason for something like this to throw an error :

```
Sub EnsureLength(ByRef Cell As Range)
    If InRange(Cell, Range("A2:A99999")) Then
        Dim Length As Integer
        Length = 20
        Dim Text As String
        Text = Cell.Text

        If Len(Cell.Text) > Length Then
            Cell.Text = Left(Text, Length) 'Expected an Object.
        End If
    ElseIf InRange(Cell, Range("B2:B99999")) Then
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Change Text = Cell.Text to Text = Cell.Value

Comment: Thanks. I dislike BASIC style langauges. But VBA is by far the worse one I've seen. 

Edit: still getting the error. Edit2: Nevermind. I see that they both have to be that. VBA and its call and set nonesense XD

Comment: VBA is the worst. Unfortunately too many business scripts use it and making it obsolete would be hard. I would be so happy for Microsoft to migrate towards C#. However, it appears that they will be migrating towards VB.NET. It's an improvement I guess, but still terrible.

Comment: Hahahaha and people gripe about JavaScript. Atleast JS can be written to be pretty readable. VB you're always googling what their nonesense means.

Comment: @User3496058 You have no idea how right you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By quickly looking at your code, I would recomend you to use `.value` instead of `.text`

Quick tip for the future,

`.text` returns the "cell" representation of the string so it may sometimes return #####, and weird strings like such.

`.value` gives you the "core" value of the cell (string, int, boolean, etc..) so usually when using VBA it's a better option!

Comment: VBA might be one of the least intuitive languages I've seen. They really need to add the option for a C# script or something.

Comment: `Text` and `Value` aren't part of the VBA language, but part of the Excel Object Model.  Go to any other language and they'll still be there if you're working with Excel.

Comment: Yeah that's right, I think I remember that now from dealing with the excel interop in C#. But C# had better debuging tools, so it wasn't so hard to figure out.